# Assign multiple lines in single cell in Excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel, ms-office

I am using a Windows application and I export a datatable into an Excel sheet. It displays successfully. Now I want to have multiple lines in a single cell. How can I do this by using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use "\n" in the String

```
Excel.Range dataRange= (Excel.Range)excelWorksheet.get_Range("C4", "C4");
dataRange.Value2 = "This is the first line\n" +
        "This is the second line\n" +          
        thirdLineString;
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the lines you want and put them into an array, and then join them into a single string, split by the newline character:

```
String singleCell = String.Join("\n",lines)
```

and then drop that string into the cell.